# How to create PopOver with direction arrow in android?

Tags: android, xml, popover

Is there any library for creating the `PopOver` in android with arrow direction base on which button pressed i googled for some time but can't found it, so Please suggest me some libraries for doing this.
Thanks You

[image]

Comment: You can open the custom dialog with the 9 patch image. it's easy for the popOver look.

Comment: But how to handle with diffrent direction?

Comment: @Nicky Check it https://github.com/lupidan/PopoverView